# MIT Scheme generic operator table package

Tags: generics, scheme, message

One problem on one of my practice exams is centered around message passing and data directed program. It asks for a procedure that utilizes the table initializing these install packages:

```
(define (attach-tag tag data) (cons tag data))
(define (get-tag data) (car data))
(define (get-contents data) (cdr data))

(define (install-metric-package)
; internal procedures
(define (get-kilometers d) d)
(define (get-miles d) (/ d 1.6))
(define (make-from-kilometers d) d)
(define (make-from-miles d) (* d 1.6))
; install metric packages
(2d-put! 'get-kilometers 'metric get-kilometers)
(2d-put! 'get-miles 'metric get-miles)
(2d-put! 'make-from-kilometers 'metric
   (lambda(d) (attach-tag 'metric (make-from-kilometers d))))
(2d-put! 'make-from-miles 'metric
   (lambda(d) (attach-tag 'metric (make-from-miles d))))
'done)

(define (install-english-package)
; internal procedures
(define (get-kilometers d) (* d 1.6))
(define (get-miles d) d)
(define (make-from-kilometers d) (/ d 1.6))
(define (make-from-miles d) d)
; install english packages
(2d-put! 'get-kilometers 'english get-kilometers)
(2d-put! 'get-miles 'english get-miles)
(2d-put! 'make-from-kilometers 'english
   (lambda(d) (attach-tag 'english (make-from-kilometers d))))
(2d-put! 'make-from-miles 'english
   (lambda(d) (attach-tag 'english (make-from-miles d))))
'done)
```

and allows the generic operators to work. Normally, I would have some code to show effort on my part, but for about a day, I've been completely stumped on how to even BEGIN with this one. All I'm given to start with is this:

```
(define (generic-op operator object)
```

I do remember having a lab on this, but it was basically taking an already-existing generic procedure and creating simple procedures to get values already contained within it. If anyone can shed some light on how to approach this, I would appreciate it greatly. Again, I'm sorry that I have nothing to show on my part, but I honestly do not know what to do here.

Comment: CSCI 1901 at the University of Minnesota?

Comment: They don't offer any solutions to these practice exams, so we're pretty much left to our own devices in that regard. While some of the problems are easy enough to figure out with an interpreter, others like these are tricky to nail on the head (at least for me).

Comment: I only ask because I took this course last semester, and happen to really enjoy scheme.  Was my answer enough for you to go on?  I left out an explicit answer, but if you 'plug-in' a few of the given procedures at the top to my form, you'll get the right answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm late replying to you on this, but I was able to find a solution. You were in fact able to help get me started, and I succeeded in finding the solution with help from a fellow student. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `2d-put!` procedure is simply adding entries to the table.  After you run the `install-*-package` code you end up with something like this (where `[proc]` is one of the procedures defined in your given code):

```
                      | 'metric | 'english |
'make-from-kilometers | [proc]  |  [proc]  |
'make-from-miles      | [proc]  |  [proc]  |
'get-kilometers       | [proc]  |  [proc]  |
'get-miles            | [proc]  |  [proc]  |
```

Then you're going to use `2d-get` in the body of `generic-op` so that whenever you call the procedure on a piece of tagged data your program will know which version (metric/english) of the procedure it should use.

```
(define (generic-op operator object)
    ((2d-get [first-tag] [second-tag]) [data]))
```

In this form the `[first-tag]` will just be the symbol used to designate the operator, e.g. `'get-miles`, the `[second-tag]` will be the symbol that was attached to the data which you can access with the given procedure `get-tag`, and `[data]` is the number that you actually want to do the operation on which you can access with the given procedure `get-contents`.  Assemble all that into a final answer for something like this:

```
(define (generic-op operator object)
    ((2d-get operator (get-tag object)) (get-contents object)))
```